# How to handle user loggin identifier change with Node/Express/Passport?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

In my application, users sign in use their email as the unique identifier. But I am asked to implement a function which lets user change their email in the profile page after they log in. The issue is even if I can make the database successfully update, the client session stores the old information. Then if I try to do (e.g. `GET`) something, the `req.user.email` will not be in the database. How to handle such issue? Or in another word, how to update the express session correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Once you sure the user data can be put in the session, you can just call `req.logIn` again (this function has been called by passport in the login process), and it will call the process correctly (e.g. calling the `serializeUser` function, etc)

```
req.logIn(newUser, function (err) { 
        if (err) {
            // Ops! Something went wrong!!
        }

    });
```

Hope it can help!